# SOLVED : Sharepoint down : Connection Close

Tags: 2013, error

Using SP2013. I deleted a subsite of the main collection site.
Now sharepoint is displaying :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Tue, 03 Jun 2014 08:58:05 GMT
Connection: close
```

It seems like it deleted the entire site collection. And I can't do a

```
Restore-SPSite http://mysharepoint.domain.com/
```

How to solve this ... I restarted the SP server ... no way ...

I can do a Get-SPDeletedSite, and retrieve the id of my site. But the Resrote-SPDeledSite is asking me for a -Path  .. I don't have this backup ... how can I do ?

OK, I solved it by using this :

```
Get-SPDeletedSite | Restore-SPDeletedSite
```

If it can help (because everybody was crazy here !)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it was a subsite and not the main web site of the Site collection?

You can use Central Administration to check your Site Collection -> Application Management -> Site Collections -> View all site collections and maybe you will find some answers there.

And you can also try an iisreset.

Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: In fact, I went in a subsite that I wanted to delete. Unfortunately, the subsite had errors, so it brings me to the main site, then I deleted the site, thinking I was on the broken subsite. So I deleted the main collection site ... Solved it using : `Get-SPDeletedSite | Restore-SPDeletedSite`. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in fact, I deleted the main site collection, because the subsite was broken and when I clicked on it, it brings me on the main site collection.
So when I clicked on delete, I didn't delete what I was supposed to do.

In order to restore the main site collection, I used powershell.

`Restore-SPDeletedSite` works only if you have a backup to set `-Path`.

If, like me, you do not have this backup, use this instead :

```
Get-SPDeletedSite | Restore-SPDeletedSite
```

Comment: i faced the same situation like one of my 2010 entire site deleted and restored successfully with Get-SPDeletedSite | Restore-SPDeletedSite
Thankyou ver much

Answer (score 0):

Please check event viewer where you will see the exact issue. Then provide  appropriate permissions on your content DB to that user.

Exception will log as follows.
Login failed for user 'DBT_svc_user'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'WSS_ContentDB'

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved after creating top level site(root) collection.

**The new top-level site was created successfully with the specified URL. If you have permission to view the Web site, you can do so in a new browser window by clicking the URL. To return to SharePoint Central Administration, click OK .**

Answer (score 0):

in my instance sharepoint timer jobs on sp servers were not running. i started the sptimer service on all the servers and started working again.